# Run different tasks in parallel on multiple hosts using Fabric/Python

Tags: parallel-processing, fabric

I have a python script using Fabric that I want to use to run customised versions of the same test on different hosts, this is done by connecting to those hosts remotely and then running a SSH command from there.

Fabric easily lets you run tasks on multiple hosts but I cant find a way to run different tasks on different hosts at the same time:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import os, time
from Config import *
from subprocess import Popen

env.source   = source
env.file     = testRunFile
env.set      = environmentSettings


@hosts(remote1) 
def rem1():
    env.user = user
    env.password = passw
    env.shell = tsch


    print ('%s' % remote1)
    print ('--------------------------------------------------')
    print ("%s REMOTE TEST" %(remote1))
    print ('--------------------------------------------------')
    print ('')

    with  prefix('setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH'), prefix ('%s' %(env.set)), prefix("cd %s" % (env.source)) :
            run ("./%s '%s' -d %s  -v -j %s -%s %s dir=%s --target=myriad2" % (env.file, test_report, test_on1, proc1, opt_level1, test_timeouts1, staging_root))

            with prefix("cd ~walshs/WORK/Compilers/moviCompile/tests/reports"):
                run ("python %s" % (test_file))
```

Comment: Any Help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, though using a different method:

I simply created a batch file that I can choose to run the fabric commands either in the background or not at the same time. Much easier